Adminjs Resource's Hamburger menu disappears on large screen but works fine on smaller screens
I am using Admin.js as a control panel for my application. Adminjs navbar contains a hamburger menu on the left to access the defined resources. This hamburger menu disappears automatically on large screens but works fine on smaller screens or if I zoomed in. What should I do to make it always visible.

